# Select latest record from one of two tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to select a single record from one of two tables based on a primary key from another table.  So a "MASTER" table and two other tables, the two other tables each having a FK JOB_ID and a column with a date.  I want to grab the record based on the latest date from one of those two tables for a given job id.  Example (I know, the table and column names and values don't make much sense, this is all fake data but you'll get the idea). There are a lot more columns in those two extra tables that I would need to include in the results, this is for simplicity.  It is in Oracle also.

JOB_TABLE

```
JOB_ID    JOB_NAME      JOB_ASSIGN
1         A job         Tom
2         Another job   Shawn
3         And another   Jason
```

JOB_SUB_1_TABLE

```
JOB_ID    SUB_JOB_ID     COMPLETION_DATE
1         1              03/09/2015
1         2              03/08/2015
2         1              <null>
3         1              02/28/2015
3         2              03/01/2015
```

JOB_SUB_2_TABLE

```
JOB_ID    SUB_JOB_ID   START_DATE
1         3             03/08/2015
1         4             01/06/2015
2         2             03/07/2015
3         3             03/10/2015
```

With this data, it I want the results to be:

```
JOB_ID    JOB_NAME      JOB_ASSIGN     SUB_JOB_ID     DATE
1         A job         Tom            1              03/09/2015
2         Another job   Shawn          2              03/07/2015
3         And another   Jason          3              03/10/2015
```

The closest I can seem to get is something like this:

```
SELECT JOB_ID,
       JOB_NAME,
       JOB_ASSIGN,
       SUB_JOB_ID,
       DATE
FROM   (SELECT JOB_ID,
               JOB_NAME,
               JOB_ASSIGN,
               SUB_JOB_ID,
               COMPLETION_DATE AS "DATE"
        FROM   JOB_SUB_1_TABLE
        WHERE  completion_date IN(SELECT Max(competion_date)
                                  FROM   JOB_SUB_1_TABLE
                                  GROUP  BY job_id,
                                            sub_job_id)
        UNION
        SELECT JOB_ID,
               JOB_NAME,
               JOB_ASSIGN,
               SUB_JOB_ID,
               START_DATE AS "DATE"
        FROM   JOB_SUB_2_TABLE
        WHERE  completion_date IN(SELECT Max(competion_date)
                                  FROM   JOB_SUB_2_TABLE
                                  GROUP  BY job_id,
                                            sub_job_id))
```

Comment: So, what does that query return, and how is it different from what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also approach the problem this way. The `nulls last` is what leads 3/7/15 to appear rather than the null for job 2 as suggested by Faber

```
select x.job_id,
       y.job_name,
       y.job_assign,
       x.sub_job_id,
       x.completion_date as dt
  from (select x.*,
               row_number() over(  partition by job_id
                                       order by completion_date desc
                                                nulls last
                                ) as rn
          from (select *
                  from job_sub_1_table
                union all
                select *
                  from job_sub_2_table) x) x
  join job_table y
    on x.job_id = y.job_id
 where x.rn = 1
```

**Fiddle test:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/175060/2/0

Comment: Is it necessary to order by `job_id` if you're already partitioning by `job_id`? I would not think that would have any effect. Also, to rank `NULL` dates last you can just do: `ORDER BY completion_date DESC NULLS LAST` (by default `NULL` values are ranked first when the sort order is `DESC`)

Comment: Yes, you're right (re: both), changed to use `nulls last` syntax

Answer (score 1):

You can rank over the dates. Since you have two similar detail tables, you can union those, join them on the master table, and then rank over the date from the two child tables. The result should look similar to this:

```
SELECT  X.JOB_ID, 
        X.JOB_NAME, 
        X.JOB_ASSIGN,
        X.SUB_JOB_ID,
        X.JOB_DATE,
FROM  ( SELECT  T.JOB_ID, 
                T.JOB_NAME, 
                T.JOB_ASSIGN,
                ST.SUB_JOB_ID,
                ST.JOB_DATE,
                DENSE_RANK() 
                  OVER ( PARTITION BY T.JOB_ID 
                         ORDER BY ST.JOB_DATE DESC) AS DATERANK

        FROM    JOB_TABLE T
        JOIN (  SELECT  JOB_ID, 
                        SUB_JOB_ID, 
                        COMPLETION_DATE AS JOB_DATE
                FROM    JOB_SUB_1_TABLE ST1
                UNION ALL
                SELECT  JOB_ID, 
                        SUB_JOB_ID, 
                        START_DATE 
                FROM    JOB_SUB_2_TABLE ST2
              ) ST ON ST.JOB_ID = T.JOB_ID
      ) X
WHERE
  X.DATERANK = 1
```